# How to send OTP verification code using Firebase email service?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I want to use the services provided by Firebase to manage the accounts in my app. Due to the requirements, it is necessary to send a verification code to the email, either Google or email and password. I know it is possible to send this code to a phone, but is it possible to send this code to email and use it as a form of verification instead of using the link provided by Firebase?

Comment: Are you specifically saying you dont want to use email link verification that is provided by Firebase? And instead you want to use a code that is emailed?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the link sent in the email?

Comment: @ColdLogic Yes, that's what I'm saying. I want to know if I can send a code, just a verification code to the email using firebase services

Comment: @AlexMamo Why just use the link? Due to the current requirements and how the flow of the app was thought, it is necessary to use a verification code by e-mail

Comment: @devblock Excluding the reasoning for needing an email code, there is not a check box way. It is possible to do this by adding in a database hook that sends an email using a cloud function with a email service integration. Its pretty trivial, but a lot of extra work. There isnt just a "send this code to email" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you're trying to achieve is a Multi Factor Authentication with a different provider than SMS. Unfortunately, Firebase is still in the process of adding support for more second factors than just SMS, thus email is not currently supported.

However, recently Firebase added support for TOTP, which let's you use authenticators like Google Authenticator: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/totp-mfa

Comment: It's really not so much a 2-Step Verification, it's just instead of using a link to verify the email or account, use a code that's sent via email.